# gtsummary tbl_svysummary with error when working with replicate weights

Tags: r, survey, gtsummary

I was trying to use tbl_svysummary with a survey object with replicate weights. The following error message was returned with `r by = ambulance`. I couldn't figure out which part I specified wrong or if tbl_svysummary just can't handle replicate weights? Thank you for your help in advance.

```
library(survey)
library(gtsummary)

data(scd)
repweights<-2*cbind(c(1,0,1,0,1,0), c(1,0,0,1,0,1), c(0,1,1,0,0,1),
                    c(0,1,0,1,1,0))
scdrep<-svrepdesign(data=scd, type="BRR", repweights=repweights, combined.weights=FALSE)

scd_svy <- srvyr::as_survey(scdrep) 

scd_svy |>
  tbl_svysummary(by = ambulance,
                 include = ESA,
                 statistic = all_categorical() ~ "{p} ({p.std.error})")
```

Error in `mutate()`:
ℹ In argument: `df_stats = pmap(...)`.
Caused by error in `pmap()`:
ℹ In index: 1.
Caused by error in `set_names()`:
! The size of `nm` (5) must be compatible with the size of `x` (4).
Run `rlang::last_trace()` to see where the error occurred.

I was expecting a summary table with ESA as row and the two levels of ambulance as columns, and for each level returned the weighted p and it's se.

Comment: Replicate weights are not currently supported. You can subscribe to this Github Issue and you'll be notified when there has been progress on this.
https://github.com/ddsjoberg/gtsummary/issues/1441

Comment: Thank you for your reply! Will subscribe for future notice!